# Как загрузить картинку из облака через Picasso?

Tags: java, android, picasso

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность загружать картинки с личного облачного хранилища через Picasso? При добавление в метод .load загрузка не получается...есть ли способ загружать изображение?
[Пример ссылки.](https://mega.nz/file/WZxlmbqD#AGsksdPjrl-BozoPlDWHUpTTWpj7tQdJqknnPFLXXoo)

Comment: добавьте `.loggingEnabled(true)` и посмотрите что в логах при попытке загрузить, и покажите ваш код который используется вами

Comment: И где по ссылке изображение? Будет ссылка корректной, будет грузиться. Вопрос к провайдеру хранилища.

Comment: из облака вы загружаете не картинку, а файл который является картинкой . Пикассо же может грузить картинки по прямой ссылке. У некоторых облачных хранилищ есть API для работы используя которые можно качать картинки напрямую.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso (равно как и Glide/Fresco/UIL) работает только с прямой ссылкой, то есть должен быть URL указывающий на вашу картинку. По умолчанию в Mega (да и в любом облаке) все ссылки недоступны извне, чтобы они были общедоступные их нада расшарить (share) - обычно клик на правую кнопку мыши и выбрать что то типа: *get link, share* и т.д.

[Документация в помощь](https://mega.nz/help)